# Spacy's BERT model doesn't learn

Tags: python, spacy, text-classification, multiclass-classification, bert-language-model

I've been trying to use `spaCy`'s pretrained BERT model `de_trf_bertbasecased_lg` to increase accuracy in my classification project. I used to build a model from scratch using `de_core_news_sm` and everything worked fine: I had an accuracy around 70%. But now I am using BERT pretrained model instead and I'm getting 0% accuracy. I don't believe that it's working so bad, so I'm assuming that there is just a problem with my code. I might have missed something important but I can't figure out what. I used the code in [this article](https://explosion.ai/blog/spacy-transformers) as an example.

Here is my code:

```
import spacy
from spacy.util import minibatch
from random import shuffle

spacy.require_gpu()
nlp = spacy.load('de_trf_bertbasecased_lg')

data = get_data()  # get_data() function returns a list with train data (I'll explain later how it looks)

textcat = nlp.create_pipe("trf_textcat", config={"exclusive_classes": False})

for category in categories:  # categories - a list of 21 different categories used for classification
    textcat.add_label(category)
nlp.add_pipe(textcat)

num = 0  # number used for counting batches
optimizer = nlp.resume_training()
for i in range(2):
    shuffle(data)
    losses = {}
    for batch in minibatch(data):
        texts, cats = zip(*batch)
        nlp.update(texts, cats, sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
        num += 1

        if num % 10000 == 0:  # test model's performance every 10000 batches
            acc = test(nlp)  # function test() will be explained later
            print(f'Accuracy: {acc}')

nlp.to_disk('model/')
```

Function `get_data()` opens files with different categories, creates a tuple like this one `(text, {'cats' : {'category1': 0, 'category2':1, ...}})`, gathers all these tuples into one array, which is then being returned to the main function.

Function `test(nlp)` opens the file with test data, predicts categories for each line in the file and checks, whether the prediction was correct.

Again, everything worked just fine with `de_core_news_sm`, so I'm pretty sure that functions `get_data()` and `test(nlp)` are working fine. Code above looks like in example but still 0% accuracy.I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**UPDATE**

Trying to understand the above problem I decided to try the model with only a few examples (just like it is advised [here](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-transformers/issues/144)). Here is the code:

```
import spacy
from spacy.util import minibatch
import random
import torch

train_data = [
    ("It is realy cool", {"cats": {"POSITIVE": 1.0, "NEGATIVE": 0.0}}),
    ("I hate it", {"cats": {"POSITIVE": 0.0, "NEGATIVE": 1.0}})
]

is_using_gpu = spacy.prefer_gpu()
if is_using_gpu:
    torch.set_default_tensor_type("torch.cuda.FloatTensor")

nlp = spacy.load("en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg")
textcat = nlp.create_pipe("trf_textcat", config={"exclusive_classes": True})
for label in ("POSITIVE", "NEGATIVE"):
    textcat.add_label(label)
nlp.add_pipe(textcat)

optimizer = nlp.resume_training()
for i in range(10):
    random.shuffle(train_data)
    losses = {}
    for batch in minibatch(train_data):
        texts, cats = zip(*batch)
        nlp.update(texts, cats, sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
    print(i, losses)
print()

test_data = [
    "It is really cool",
    "I hate it",
    "Great!",
    "I do not think this is cool"
]

for line in test_data:
    print(line)
    print(nlp(line).cats)
```

And the output was:

```
0 {'trf_textcat': 0.125}
1 {'trf_textcat': 0.12423406541347504}
2 {'trf_textcat': 0.12188033014535904}
3 {'trf_textcat': 0.12363225221633911}
4 {'trf_textcat': 0.11996611207723618}
5 {'trf_textcat': 0.14696261286735535}
6 {'trf_textcat': 0.12320466339588165}
7 {'trf_textcat': 0.12096124142408371}
8 {'trf_textcat': 0.15916231274604797}
9 {'trf_textcat': 0.1238454058766365}

It is really cool
{'POSITIVE': 0.47827497124671936, 'NEGATIVE': 0.5217249989509583}
I hate it
{'POSITIVE': 0.47827598452568054, 'NEGATIVE': 0.5217240452766418}
Great!
{'POSITIVE': 0.4782750606536865, 'NEGATIVE': 0.5217249393463135}
I do not think this is cool
{'POSITIVE': 0.478275328874588, 'NEGATIVE': 0.5217246413230896}
```

Not only the model performs bad, the loss is not getting smaller and scores for all the test sentences are almost the same. And most importantly: it didn't even get those questions correct, that happened to be in the train data. So my question is: does the model even learn? And what am I doing wrong?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received an answer to my question on [GitHub](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-transformers/issues/180) and it looks like there must be some optimizer parameters specified, just like in [this example](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-transformers/blob/v0.6.x/examples/train_textcat.py).