# How to improve a German text classification model in spaCy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, text-classification

I am working on a text classification project and using `spacy` for this. Right now I have an accuracy equal to almost 70% but that is not enough. I've been trying to improve the model for past two weeks, but no successful results so far. And here I am looking for an advice about what I should do or try. Any help would be highly appreciated!

So, here is what I do so far:

> 1) Preparing the data:

I have an unbalanced dataset of German news with 21 categories (like `POLITICS`, `ECONOMY`, `SPORT`, `CELEBRITIES` etc). In order to make categories equal I duplicate small classes. As a result I have 21 files with almost `700 000` lines of text. I then normalize this data using the following code:

```
import spacy
from charsplit import Splitter

POS = ['NOUN', 'VERB', 'PROPN', 'ADJ', 'NUM']  # allowed parts of speech

nlp_helper = spacy.load('de_core_news_sm')
splitter = Splitter()

def normalizer(texts):
    arr = []  # list of normalized texts (will be returned from the function as a result of normalization)

    docs = nlp_helper.pipe(texts)  # creating doc objects for multiple lines
    for doc in docs:  # iterating through each doc object
        text = []  # list of words in normalized text
        for token in doc:  # for each word in text
            token = token.lemma_.lower()

            if token not in stop_words and token.pos_ in POS:  # deleting stop words and some parts of speech
                if len(word) > 8 and token.pos_ == 'NOUN':  # only nouns can be splitted
                    _, word1, word2 = splitter.split_compound(word)[0]  # checking only the division with highest prob
                    word1 = word1.lower()
                    word2 = word2.lower()
                    if word1 in german and word2 in german:
                        text.append(word1)
                        text.append(word2)
                    elif word1[:-1] in german and word2 in german:  # word[:-1] - checking for 's' that joins two words
                        text.append(word1[:-1])
                        text.append(word2)
                    else:
                        text.append(word)
                else:
                    text.append(word)
        arr.append(re.sub(r'[.,;:?!"()-=_+*&^@/\']', ' ', ' '.join(text))) # delete punctuation
    return arr
```

Some explanations to the above code:

`POS` - a list of allowed parts of speech. If the word I'm working with at the moment is a part of speech that is not in this list -> I delete it.

`stop_words` - just a list of words I delete.

`splitter.split_compound(word)[0]` - returns a tuple with the most likely division of the compound word (I use it to divide long German words into shorter and more widely used). Here is the [link](https://github.com/dtuggener/CharSplit) to the repository with this functionality.

To sum up: I find the lemma of the word, make it lower case, delete stop words and some parts of speech, divide compound words, delete punctuation. I then join all the words and return an array of normalized lines.

> 2) Training the model

I train my model using `de_core_news_sm` (to make it possible in the future to use this model not only for classification but also for normalization). Here is the code for training:

```
nlp = spacy.load('de_core_news_sm')

textcat = nlp.create_pipe('textcat', config={"exclusive_classes": False, "architecture": 'simple_cnn'})
nlp.add_pipe(textcat, last=True)
for category in categories:
    textcat.add_label(category)

pipe_exceptions = ["textcat"]
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe not in pipe_exceptions]

with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):
    optimizer = nlp.begin_training()

    for i in range(n_iter):
        shuffle(data)
        batches = spacy.util.minibatch(data)

        for batch in batches:
            texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
            nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.25)
```

Some explanations to the above code:

`data` - list of lists, where each list includes a line of text and a dictionary with categories (just like in the [docs](https://spacy.io/usage/training#textcat))

'categories' - list of categories

'n_iter' - number of iterations for training

> 3) At the end I just save the model with `to_disk` method.

With the above code I managed to train a model with 70% accuracy. Here is a list of what I've tried so far to improve this score:

> 1) Using another architecture (`ensemble`) - didn't give any improvements
>
> 2) Training on non normalized data - the result was much worse
>
> 3) Using pretrained BERT model - could'n do it ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61943409/spacys-bert-model-doesnt-learn) is my unanswered question about it)
>
> 4) Training `de_core_news_md` instead of `de_core_news_sm` - didn't give any improvements (tried it because according to the [docs](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity#basics) there could be an improvement thanks to the vectors (if I understood it correctly). Correct me if I'm wrong)
>
> 5) Training on data, normalized in a slightly different way (without lower casing and punctuation deletion) - didn't give any improvements
>
> 6) Changing dropout - didn't help

So right now I am a little stuck about what to do next. I would be very grateful for any hint or advice.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would suggest is increasing your batch size. After that your optimizer (Adam if possible) and learning rate for which I don't see the code here. You can finally try changing your dropout.

Also, if you are trying neural networks and plan on changing a lot, it would be better if you could switch to PyTorch or TensorFlow. In PyTorch, you will have HuggingFace library, which has BERT in-built in it.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I will definitely try changing batch size, optimizer and learning rate. I've already tried changing dropout - didn't help (sorry, forgot to add it to the list of what I've tried). Also, I will consider swithcing to `PyTorch` or `TensorFlow`, I was just hoping that it is possible to use `BERT` in `spaCy` (like in this blog post: `https://explosion.ai/blog/spacy-transformers`). Unfortunately I couldn't do it, so I'm just waiting for someone to answer the question :) (`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61943409/spacys-bert-model-doesnt-learn`)

Comment: I'll try what you advised and be back with the results)

Comment: I tried training the model with a bunch of different parameters. Unfortunately, none of them worked for me:( But I guess it's just my case, and it could still work for others, so I'll accept your answer. Thanks!